# Speed up adding Poisson noise to an image

Tags: image-processing, random, performance-tuning, distributions

I'm simulating some images corrupted with Poisson noise, but I'm encountering a few problems with performance. According to the documentation on [`ImageEffect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageEffect.html), one can add Poisson noise according to the following rule:

[image]

Loading up an example image, and running the code:

```
man256 = ImageAdjust[ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Man"}], {256, 256}]];
ImageAdjust[ImageEffect[man256, {"PoissonNoise", 0.8}]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* 10.839 seconds *)
```

Subsequently running it again in the same kernel, it only takes 0.196 seconds. Meanwhile, the Gaussian noise effect:

```
ImageAdjust[ImageEffect[man256, {"GaussianNoise", 4.}]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* 0.014 seconds *)
```

And then running it again once more, it only takes 0.006 seconds.

I tried defining my own functions for adding Poisson and Gaussian noise for comparison. Note that I define the amount of Poisson noise slightly differently to the Mathematica method (in a way that actually makes more sense to me).

```
addPoissonNoise[x_, peak_] :=
  Block[{imagedata},
   imagedata = peak*ImageData[x];
   Map[If[# == 0., 0., RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[#]]] &, imagedata, {2}]
   ];

addGaussianNoise[x_, sig_] :=
  Block[{imagedata},
   imagedata = ImageData[x];
   Map[# + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., sig]] &, imagedata, {2}]
   ];

ImageAdjust[Image[addPoissonNoise[man256, 40.]]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 6.495 seconds *)

ImageAdjust[Image[addGaussianNoise[man256, 4.]]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.007 seconds *)
```

So on an initial run, my code is faster than the built-in code in both cases. But on subsequent runs, it's slower than the built-in code. Considerably slower in the case of Poisson noise.

The Gaussian example is only for comparison - it's the Poisson noise I'm more interested in, and speeding up the **initial** run of the code, as ~10 seconds is considerably slower than I'd like, and in reality my images are bigger than 256x256 pixels.

Is there any way to speed-up the corruption of an image with Poisson noise?

**Update #1**

Replacing `Map` with `ParallelMap` speeds up my Poisson noise function, but it's still quite slow (taking about 1.89 seconds on my machine).

Avoiding multiple calls to `RandomVariate` is hard to avoid, I think. It's a shame `PoissonDistribution` can't be compiled ([Which Distributions can be Compiled using RandomVariate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/which-distributions-can-be-compiled-using-randomvariate)).

**Update #2**

There's this question: [Why is Poisson Random Deviate Generation so slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/why-is-poisson-random-deviate-generation-so-slow)

(For info, this is with v10 on Win8.1)

Comment: Why not just generate a random image using Poisson, then add/multiply/subtract as appropriate from base image? Much faster.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but is that method appropriate for Poisson noise, which depends on the underlying pixel value of the base image? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @rasher, as blochwave correctly states, the distribution parameter depends on the individual pixel values so you can't simply generate a whole array of random values from a single distribution.

Comment: You mention speeding up the initial run of the code, and that it's a shame that `PoissonDistribution` can't be compiled. In fact the delay on the initial run is caused by compiling code to provide the Poisson distribution :-) You can look at ``Image`ColorOperationsDump`iImageEffectPoissonNoise`` to see how it works internally.

Comment: Indeed, as `Information[Image`ColorOperationsDump`PoissonNoise2D]` shows, it involves `RandomReal[NormalDistribution[]]`, which does compile.

Comment: Thanks for noting the internal mechanism @SimonWoods - inspired me towards an answer!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) points out in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56180/speed-up-adding-poisson-noise-to-an-image#comment161380_56180) that:

> In fact the delay on the initial run is caused by compiling code to
>   provide the Poisson distribution :-) You can look at
>   `` Image`ColorOperationsDump`iImageEffectPoissonNoise `` to see how it works
>   internally.

Now, although `PoissonDistribution` [can't be compiled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/which-distributions-can-be-compiled-using-randomvariate), there's nothing stopping the use of my own C++ function and calling it with `LibraryLink`.

So that's what I tried! Working with the code by [Arnoud Buzing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/105/arnoud-buzing) from [Minimal effort method for integrating C++ functions into Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8442/13162), I wrote some C++ code (given at the bottom of this answer) that utilises the [Poisson distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/poisson_distribution/) built into C++.

My Mathematica code is then:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
poissonNoiseLib = CreateLibrary[
    {ToString[NotebookDirectory[]] <> "/poissonnoise.cpp"}, 
    "poissonNoiseLib",
    "Debug" -> False
  ];
poissonNoise = LibraryFunctionLoad[
    poissonNoiseLib, 
    "poissonNoise",
    {{Real, 2}},
    {Real, 2}
  ];
(* Takes 5.18 seconds to do all this *)
```

So let's reimport the image, but make it much bigger this time.

```
man2048 = ImageAdjust[ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Man"}], {2048, 2048}]];
img1 = ImageAdjust[ImageEffect[man2048, {"PoissonNoise", 0.8}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Takes 21.64 seconds first time round *)
(* Subsequently takes 11.45 seconds even after the function has been compiled *)

poissonpeak = 50.;
man2048data = poissonpeak * ImageData[man2048];
img2 = ImageAdjust[Image[poissonNoise[man2048data]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Takes 0.98 seconds *)
```

[image]

If you include the time it takes to compile my function using `LibraryLink`, I have a first-time run of 6.16 seconds, and subsequent runs of 0.98 seconds, for an image 2048x2048 pixels. This is compared to 11.45 seconds for the built-in function. I could even look into parallelising the C++ code below, for a further speed-up.

A 10x speed-up isn't bad, plus I learned how to use `LibraryLink` along the way :-)

---

**C++ code**

```cpp
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){return WolframLibraryVersion;}
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {return 0;}
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int poissonNoise(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){

    int err; // error code

    MTensor m1; // input tensor
    MTensor m2; // output tensor

    mint const* dims; // dimensions of the tensor

    double* data1; // actual data of the input tensor
    double* data2; // data for the output tensor

    mint i; // bean counters
    mint j;

    m1 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    dims = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(m1);
    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 2, dims,&m2);
    data1 = libData->MTensor_getRealData(m1);
    data2 = libData->MTensor_getRealData(m2);

    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::default_random_engine generator (seed); // RNG

    for(i=0;i<dims[0];i++) {
        for(j=0;j<dims[1];j++) {
            if(data1[i*dims[1]+j]==0.)
            {
                data2[i*dims[1]+j] = 0.; // If pixel value is 0, return 0
            }
            else
            {
                std::poisson_distribution<int> distribution(data1[i*dims[1]+j]); // Poisson distribution
                data2[i*dims[1]+j] = distribution(generator); // If pixel value is >0, sample from the distribution
            }
        }
    }

    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, m2);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```