# Speeding Up RandomVariate

Tags: performance-tuning, random

Consider the following code where we first take 1000 independent samples from a Poisson distribution, and then take 1000 independent samples from 1000 different Poisson distributions:

```
list = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 0.1],1000];
RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[0.5], 1000] // Timing // First
RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[#]] & /@ list // Timing // First
```

which on my machine outputs something like `0.000343` and `0.137541`, respectively.
Note that it obviously doesn't matter if `list` contains different numbers or identical numbers.

Clearly `RandomVariate` has some kind of overhead. Is there a way to improve the efficiency of sampling from a list of distributions that vary only in their parameters?

Comment: `RandomInteger[PoissonDistribution[#]] & /@ list` is `slightly` faster

Comment: Poisson-specific possible duplicate: [(56180)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56180) and general-distribution possible duplicate [(75303)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75303/can-mathematicas-random-number-generation-be-improved/75305#75305). Note also that attempting to compile with a Poisson distribution won't work, as per [(1124)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/which-distributions-can-be-compiled-using-randomvariate)

Comment: And in fact, another Poisson-based possible duplicate [(35433)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/why-is-poisson-random-deviate-generation-so-slow)

Comment: Thanks. The last one you mentioned seems the most like a duplicate, and there are some good answers there, but I am most interested in a distribution-independent solution, which does not seem to be asked or answered elsewhere.

Comment: Well [(75303)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75303/can-mathematicas-random-number-generation-be-improved) is probably closest - for a distribution-independent solution, you can turn either to a C++ solution, or the [clever method presented by @ciao](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75304/13162)

Comment: @blochwave [Oxymoron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron) :D

Answer (score 5):

Per your example case:

```
(* setup (you'll pay time here, but once done, it's done) *)
dist = ParameterMixtureDistribution[PoissonDistribution[m],
                                     m \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1/2, 1/10]];

pdf = PDF[dist, z];

(* pick some end-point with negligible probability *)
(* Here, using 30 truncates tail with total p of ~6.34*10^-40 *)
dc = Rule @@ Transpose@Table[{pdf /. z -> zz, zz}, {zz, 0, 30}];

(* use it and compare *)
result = RandomChoice[dc, 1000] // Timing // First

list = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 0.1], 1000];
resultold=RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[#]] & /@ list // Timing // First
```

> 0.
>
> 0.842405

Timings on netbook...

Comment: I miss the cigar lounge

Comment: @belisariusisforth: there as I type - will take a puff in your honor ;-}

Comment: `PDF[dist, z]` gives `Undefined` in 10.3.1.